# Magento Custom Product Page Price template conflict upsell products price

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, template, upgrade, conflict

using below xml i'm overriding product page's default price.phtml,

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">    
     <reference name="catalog_product_price_template">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>simple</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>catalog/product/productpageprice.phtml</template></action>
     </reference>

     .......

</catalog_product_view translate="label">
```

It's affecting my upsell products price template. Is there any way to solve this conflict and to use default price.phml ?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748333/magento-use-an-alternate-price-phtml-in-addition-to-the-existing-one) which explains how to use alternative price templates in addition to the existing default one.

Comment: For me the above layout change in a local.xml file does not change the upsell price display. Is this your only xml change or did you also change the block somehow?